# PHP: How to keep checking the value in DB and get notified in the php page when it gets changed

Tags: php, notifications, background

I have a php page to which an user logins to it. I would like to show user a notification when something in his account gets changed, Say when user is logged into his account and his account got credited with 50 usd I would like to give him a notification in the current php page that you got 50 usd. So, for this purpose I am trying to find out a method to achieve this objective.

I thought of achieving this with thread but not sure if this is an viable option or if something else is existing in the php framwork.

Please help as I am not very much familiar with Php.

Comment: The problem here isn't just php but http. If the page is delivered, no content can be passed after. Therefore you'll need Javascript, which opens requests in the background and reacts on the answers. You should search for terms as `ajax`, `FetchAPI` and `long polling`

Comment: You basically have 2 techniques - repeatedly polling the server (ajax), or opening a 2 way connection (websockets) and pushing the notification to the user. !st option is simplest but can cause high server load if the number of users is high and polling frequency is low. Second option requires installing a websocket server (not always possible, for example on shared hosting) or using a 3rd party service (pusher)

Comment: The real question you need to ask yourself is if, showing this is good enough when they reload a page or if you need to update whatever page they are on in real time.  Personally I think on reload would be fine, unless you use a lot of AJAX already to prevent page loads.  This would greatly simplify things...  Then it becomes a problem of tracking that change, then how to show it.

Comment: Other than that this is way to broad for serious answers.

Comment: Thanks to all for your suggestions.